# What are some amusing paper titles?

Tags: titles

I acknowledge that this is by no means a productive question, and I ask it for purposes of humor. Still, if anyone is aware of amusing / clever paper titles, it could be nice to make such a list.

-- Edit -- It may in fact be off-topic, as suggested by some comments. I am open to suggestions for more appropriate venues for this question.

Comment: Sorry, this is clearly off topic here. I've voted to close.

Comment: I won't vote to close this as it is one of the most original questions seen lately and has to be better than "how do I find a PhD programme"...

Comment: There are some shown here: http://www.slate.com/articles/health_and_science/science/2015/12/the_best_funny_clever_or_offensive_science_paper_titles.html?via=gdpr-consent

Comment: @Solar Mike true, but I don't see what a 'correct' answer to this could look like.

Comment: @henning of course, there are not necessarily correct answers but still, it can be useful and interesting for other people having different answers.

Comment: [Conor McBride](http://strictlypositive.org/publications.html) often uses interesting names (that I find amusing) for his paper in Computer Science: "_I am not a number: I am a free variable_", "_Everybody's Got To Be Somewhere._", "_Do be do be do_", "_Got Plenty o' Nuttin'_", etc. Check his DBLP at https://dblp.uni-trier.de/pers/hd/m/McBride:Conor

Comment: "I am open to suggestions for more appropriate venues for this question." Cafe. Tea-house. Lunch with your colleagues. Twitter. Reddit. Your blog. Oh, and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_yT472gMsSI

Comment: Relevant meta thread: we don't have a policy about big list questions, but we don't really like them, because they are a bad fit for the structured Q&A format: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/749/31917

Comment: Please, just google "funny science paper titles". There's no need to duplicate the results here. This is not a general discussion forum (there's Reddit for that).

Comment: Related thread on math papers: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44326/most-memorable-titles

Answer (score 2):

*Despacito: the slow evolutionary changes in plant microRNAs.*

(https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29448158)

Comment: Why is this amusing?

Comment: @henning I assume it is related to this well-known song https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJQP7kiw5Fk